# html table header locked to the top of the page even when scrolling down

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I've used both `to_html()` and `style.render()` of Pandas DataFrame to generate html page from CSV data. It's cool!

But when I scroll the page down I lose sight of the column names, that's the problem.

Is there some way of hanging it up on the top of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
#NAME HERE{ 
position: fixed; 
{
```

You can also do the width ect with this code...

```
 #NAME HERE{ 
 position: fixed; 
 bottom:0px; 
 right: 0; 
 width: 0px; 
 height: 0px;
 }
```

Also, if you want the width to span across the page just change the 0px to 100% Also depending on what you want, change " fixed " to " absolute "

Comment: The `position: fixed; ` does something. But it stays on top of the first content line. And, when I scroll left/right the head stays, I want it to move left/right together with the rest of the table. Would you mind to provide a full example?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the project or JsFiddle? It would help to have a visual.